# Why do I keep getting a throw er on my ternimal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js (coming from php background) , and I am trying to initialize my node server with the JS file I have set up.

Everytime I set it up I keep getting this error

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

I was wondering how can I catch this error and why do I keep getting this error? Any help would be really appreciated it

Below is my code

```
    var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    io = require("socket.io")();


app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);


var sever = app.listen(app.get('port'),function () {
    console.log("Listing on port "+ app.get("port"));
});
```

Comment: Some process already listens on port 3000. Either kill that process or use another port.

Comment: How do I find out where that process is?

Comment: Never mind I just exited my terminal and it worked.. how can I catch the error?

Comment: Like other errors: `try...catch`